# Atexit function executed at program start

Tags: python, atexit

I have this simple procedure:

```
def save_f():
    global register
    register = register_registerer()
    outFile = open('FobbySave.txt', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(register, outFile)
    outFile.close()
    print register

atexit.register(save_f())
```

The problem is that `save_f` gets called as soon as I run my program. This isn't all of my code, just the important part. If there is nothing wrong here please tell me, so that I know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
atexit.register(save_f())
```

to

```
atexit.register(save_f)
```

In your original code, the `save_f()` calls the function. The return value of the function (i.e. `None`) is then passed to `atexit.register()`.

The correct version passes the function object itself to `atexit.register()`.

Comment: Odd, this is not making the program save at all?

Answer (score 3):

You are registering the return value of the function instead of the function itself. Instead of calling it before registering, just pass in the function reference:

```
atexit.register(save_f)
```

Comment: Odd, this is not making the program save at all? But it does save when executed manually...

Comment: @madprogramer: You are using a relative path; are you certain you are looking in the correct location?

Comment: @madprogramer: that is not what I was asking. When exiting, are you certain the current working directory has not changed? Use an *absolute* path instead to be sure.

Comment: By that I don't know what you mean. I work in the same folder, save in the same folder. By ABSOLUTE path what do you mean?

Comment: @madprogramer: A full path: `/path/to/folder/and/filename.dat`. Or use: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'filename.dat')` to write in the same location as the current module.